# Simple Login using Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am new to spring and I need to secure my application with Simple Login Form.
I went over lots of resources and found them little complex.

Can anybody suggest me an article / tutorail that shows simple way to get the app behind login?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow [its own guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/start-here.html). I'd found petclinic tutorial very simple and useful.